# EJB exception while try to run the client

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, ejb

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.jnp.interf
aces.NamingContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: o
rg.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory]
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(Unknown Source)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at Client_TestPortal.main(Client_TestPortal.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFac
tory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 5 more
```

Comment: I hope [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32901871/javax-naming-noinitialcontextexception-cannot-instantiate-class) will help you to resolve this issue in Jboss 5.1

Answer (score 10):

That exception says that initializing of the `InitialContext` has failed for your `Client_TestPortal` application.  The resaon is that it has been unable to load the class `org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory` which (I presume) the default Java Naming provider for your platform.

It appears that your apps classpath is missing a required JAR file.  According to [this findjar query](http://www.findjar.com/class/org/jnp/interfaces/NamingContextFactory.html) it could be one of the following:

```
[LOCAL] jbossall-client.jar
[LOCAL] jbossjmx-ant.jar
[MAVEN2] jnpserver-3.2.3.jar
[MAVEN2] jbossall-client-3.2.1.jar
[MAVEN2] jbossall-client-3.2.3.jar
[MAVEN2] jbossjmx-ant-3.2.3.jar
[MAVEN2] jnp-client-3.2.1.jar
[MAVEN2] jnp-client-4.0.2.jar
```

... or something like that.  Which (if any) of the above JARs is most appropriate is hard to say.

Comment: Stephen,if i create bean object got this error at run time???         java.lang.ClassCastException
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow(Unknown S
ource)
        at javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow(Unknown Source)
        at Client_TestPortal.main(Client_TestPortal.java:71)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.naming.Reference
        ... 3 more

How to create bean object in my client ? i have  Interface name : TestPortal 
Bean class name : TestPortalBean

Ear name : PortalEJB

Comment: @saran - You haven't provided enough information to answer that.  Open a new Question.

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided enough information like the environment you are using, The app server etc.

Any way it lloks like JNDI related JAR is not on the classpath. If it is in place and still not working, then you may have missed to put the correct context information, so pass the JNDI information to the constuctor of InitialContext.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I found how to fix it. All you have to do is add the jbossall-client.jar library to the clients project, and done!!! You can find the file inside the client folder.
e.g jboss-6.1.0.Final_GPT\client
I was using Jboss 6.1.0
You can also get help from this link
https://community.oracle.com/thread/1157701?start=0

Hope it helps.