# javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class:

Tags: java, eclipse, ejb-3.0, jboss5.x

I'm trying to implement Simple EJB Application Described in [tutorialpoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ejb/ejb_create_application.htm) and I’m using JBoss 5.1 and eclipse as IDE and i created project as EJB 3. but I’m getting the below error

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class:   org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory]
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:674)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:242)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
at com.tutorialspoint.test.EJBTester.<init>(EJBTester.java:42)
at com.tutorialspoint.test.EJBTester.main(EJBTester.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(VersionHelper12.java:72)
at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(VersionHelper12.java:61)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:671)
... 5 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.tutorialspoint.test.EJBTester.testStatelessEjb(EJBTester.java:65)
at com.tutorialspoint.test.EJBTester.main(EJBTester.java:53)
null
```

can anyone Guide me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a jar with class `org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory` to the classpath in your client code.

You can get it [here](http://www.findjar.com/jar/jboss/jars/jbossall-client-3.2.3.jar.html;jsessionid=4FBA53D404613D7EFBA3AA32416C3746). Make sure to get the appropriate jar for jboss 5.x if you get a version mismatch error.

Comment: its work fine and i added  default jbossall-client.jar in client folder then sample is working

Comment: and what the i need to do if i want to connect same client with Jboss 7.x

Comment: Your code should work even with jboss 7.x as long as the initial context factory you use is `org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory`.